# What happens if a noble's needs aren't met?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I see that nobles can have demands, like private offices, fancy bedrooms and tombs. The only nobles I've dealt with so far have been assigned by me, and their needs have been easy to meet.

What happens if their demands go unmet? Does it work the same for elected vs. non-elected nobles?

(I'm kind of hoping for beserk rage, like strange moods that don't get what they want.)

Comment: Bad Thoughts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demands are requests for various things Nobles want that you have half a year to fulfill.  By comparison Mandates are requirements you must follow, both have similar repercussions.

If you fulfill a Demand or Mandate the Noble in question will receive a Happy [Thought](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Thought).  Failing to do so will result in an Unhappy [Thought](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Thought).  More over and unfulfilled Mandate may get sentenced to punishment for the 'violation of production order' [crime](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Justice).

Dwarven productivity is generally determined by the amount of Happy/Unhappy Thought they have.  Since most nobles are not productive this isn't usually an issue.  However, Dwarves with a large number of Unhappy thoughts can enter into (SPOILERS) [Fell](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Mood#FellVerify) or [Macabre](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Mood#Macabre) moods (the former resulting in the death of another dwarf).  Worse, they can also lead to [Tantrums](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tantrum).  The issue with Tantrums and Fell moods is that the death of a dwarf (any dwarf) can easily kick off a [Tantrum Spiral](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Fun#Dwarf_vs_Society.3F).

So do us all a favor, and meet your Noble's needs.

Comment: That's not true by the way. Quoth the wiki on Fell moods: "Strangely, none of the other dwarves seem to mind the murder."

Comment: @Arda ever had a Tantrum Spiral after a Fell mood eats your Expedition Leader? I have.  Just because they don't mind his death doesn't mean it doesn't bring down your whole fortress

Comment: You neglected to mention the hammerer.

Comment: @Cross I added a crime link.  Explaining how crimes are handled is really appropriate for a different question, but I will link to why it is 'fun.'